# Jquery - HoverIntent mouseleave - can I detect what I'm now hovering over?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, hoverintent

I'm writing an animated drop-down menu system, and unfortunately the way I've built it, my top level menu items do not contain the drop-down sub menus - they are entirely separate divs.

This is making the handling of mouse hovering tricky.

I'm running into problems getting the sub menu closing to work in all circumstances: if the mouse pointer is moved from the sub menu to its parent top menu item then I don't want the sub menu to close.
I've tried applying a 'showing' class to both the elements, and then binding the close function against moving off $(".showing"), but it doesn't seem to notice I'm leaving one .showing for another one, and it fires anyway.  You can argue that's logical, but it's not the behaviour I want!

Is there anyway to detect my new hovered class is the same as the one I've left, so I can suppress the actions?
(I did try using $(".showing").is(":hover") but it didn't work in IE, it caused an error...)

Any thoughts welcomed :)

Comment: have you thought about rewriting your mark up to use ULs and LIs. It may take a little longer, but would save you the headache of figuring out some hack job way to make this work.

Comment: Oh yes, I've certainly thought about rewriting it, but I'm working in a commercial environment where time is precious - not just mine, but for the testing team and the business users who'd have to be involved in cross-browser testing of any re-write.  If I can avoid that, I'd really like to!

Comment: By the time you've been thinking how to implement the javascript you probably could've rewrote it by now.